# OpenCart Blog module error

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I have installed this module([http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=11671][1]) in my cart but when i am try to edit the blog module it outputs me these error can anybody help me out of this. Thankyou

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 146Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 148Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 154Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 160Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 166Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 167Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 169Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 202Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 204Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 206Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 207Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 208Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 209Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 210Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 211Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 213Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 214Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 219Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 227Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 242Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 243Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 244Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 245Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 246Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 265Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 267Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerModuleBlog::$data has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 268
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ControllerModuleBlog::render() in C:\xampp\htdocs\chip\admin\controller\module\blog.php on line 276
```

Comment: *I have installed this module* - then go to ask for support the module developer. Read the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [*opencart*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opencart/info) tag wiki.

Comment: i searched over there but no idea about it, i have left a comment over the module in the support section waiting both the sides

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally i found the solution for this, hope it will help for some one
I was using 2.0.0.0 where the module supports only 1.5.6.4

and also if u want to use any modulesor this module of 1.5.6.4 verions one then you have to make changes in the module files

```
eg. 
    $this->data['insert'] =
into

    $data['insert'] =

-------------------------------------------------------
    $this->language->load('module/blog'); 

 into

    $this->load->language('module/blog');

-------------------------------------------------------------
$this->template = 'module/blog/list.tpl';
        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());

into

$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');


        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('module/blog/list.tpl', $data));
```

Comment: For next time, here is a better extension for installing blog in your opencart store,
http://www.fmeaddons.com/opencart/blog-news-articles-module.html